# Adding Sets to other Sets with "flattening" in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Groovy 2.4.x here. I have a `Set<String>`, and need to write some methods that will dynamically add other strings to that set, depending on what it's contents are:

```
Set<String> resolveAllColors(Set<String> colors) {
    if(colors.contains('Rainbow')) {
        colors << getAllRainbowColors()
    } else if(colors.contains('Red')) {
        colors << getAllRedishColors()
    }
}

Set<String> getAllRainbowColors() {
    [
        getAllRedishColors(),
        'Orange',
        'Yellow',
        'Green',
        'Blue',
        'Indigo',
        'Violet'
    ]
}

Set<String> getAllRedishColors() {
    [
        'Rose',
        'Maroon'
    ]
}
```

So as you can see, if my initial `Set<String>` contains `"Red"`, then I want to add a few more "redish" colors to that set. But if it contain `"Rainbow"`, then I want to add all "redish" colors as well as several other strings to that set.

When I run this code with the following driver:

```
class Driver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver().run()
    }

    void run() {
        Set<String> colors = [ 'White', 'Red' ]
        println resolveAllColors(colors)
    }

    // All the methods mentioned above
}
```

...then I get the following as output:

```
[ White, [ Rose, Maroon ] ]
```

Whereas I want:

```
[ White, Rose, Maroon ]
```

And when I change that `colors` set to be defined as `Set<String> colors = [ 'White', 'Rainbow' ]`, then I get:

```
[ White, [ [ Rose, Maroon ], Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet ] ]
```

Instead of:

```
[ White, Rose, Maroon, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet ]
```

Why am I getting all these nested sets, and what can I change in my code so that it all just looks like one big "flat" set of colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `+`, as it adds the other collections elements to your collection, whereas `<<` adds the whole collection as a single element.

Also note `+` doesn't mutate the list, but creates a new one.

```
Set<String> resolveAllColors(Set<String> colors) {
    if(colors.contains('Rainbow')) {
        colors + getAllRainbowColors()
    } else if(colors.contains('Red')) {
        colors + getAllRedishColors()
    }
}

Set<String> getAllRedishColors() {
    [
        'Rose',
        'Maroon'
    ]
}

Set<String> getAllRainbowColors() {
    allRedishColors + [
        'Orange',
        'Yellow',
        'Green',
        'Blue',
        'Indigo',
        'Violet'
    ]
}
```

Tests:

```
Set<String> colors = [ 'White', 'Red' ]
assert resolveAllColors(colors) == [
    'White', 
    'Red',
    'Rose', 
    'Maroon', 
] as Set

assert allRainbowColors == [
        'Rose',
        'Maroon',
        'Orange',
        'Yellow',
        'Green',
        'Blue',
        'Indigo',
        'Violet'
] as Set
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Will P (+1) - what about my `getAllRainbowColors()` method? How could I have that call `getAllRedishColors()`, add it to its local set via `+`, and then return the final set? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you find yourself with a similar need to "flatten" your collection, your answer was in the title of your question.

Change your method to return `colors.flatten()`, and you get what you want.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#flatten%28%29

Comment: Indeed, `flatten()` is really useful when your lists are already nested.